# trying to check if there is a specific word or no in the requested page with preg_match

Tags: php

```
} elseif($type == "anything"||$type == "anything") {
    $sql = $db->prepare("select * from stuff where stuff_id = :id");
    $sql->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

    $checker = trim($rows['addinfo']);
    $ch =  curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $checker);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0');`enter code here`
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $check = curl_exec($ch);
    if(preg_match('#error|Hello|file|Sofware#si',$check))
    {
        echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-success'>Found</a>";
        curl_close($ch);
    }else{
        echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>Not Found</a>";
    }
```

trying to check if there is a specific word or no  in the requested page with preg_match i need to check if the words #error|Hello|file|Sofware#si avilable or no .. if the words or one of the words available  the will echo Found  if not available echo Not Found

Comment: What happens when you execute this currently? `var_dump($check)` gives back what?

Comment: Why would you use `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` it will duplicate everything in an array you then loop over

Comment: `$type == "anything"||$type == "anything"` is also strange, maybe a typo?

Comment: @user3783243 My Guess is that this is Pseudo code and not what the OP is actually using. So for that reason I am off. Its not possible to debug pseudo code remotely it just wastes everyones time

Comment: @user3783243  string(75) "links|info|scraper|http://kexubgz.com/index.php"

anything = just to remind me   .. i have a bad memory

Comment: The length of that string is not 75 characters. You have hidden characters. The terms you are trying to match also aren't present so the issue is that you are getting `Found` when you shouldn't?? Please define the problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i'm new in PDO  and trying to go on i was using sql

Comment: @user3783243  the issue is that i'm getting Not Found when it shouldn't
because the word is already available in the other page

Comment: `error|Hello|file|Sofware` are not in `links|info|scraper|kexubgz.com/index.php`.

Comment: @Dharman Security risk because the SSL wasn't matched or how?

Comment: Yes. Someone can spoof an SSL certificate. SSL must be verified.

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is pointless.  Your pattern has no dots to modify.  It is not clear why this snippet is failing.